# How to add entry in Neighbour Table in IPV6 in linux using C/C++ Code?

Tags: c++, c, linux, network-programming, ipv6

**For IPV4, I have added the Neighbour entries in this way.**

'''

```
void assocArp(string ipAddress, const uint8_t * const macAddress, char_t interface[])
{
    int32_t sockfd;
    struct arpreq req;
    struct sockaddr_in *ptrSin;
    char_t device[20];
    (void)memcpy(device, interface, IFNAMSIZ);

     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0) {
        cout << "\n assocArp : Failure in AF_INET socket opening in assocArp in 
        IPService\n";
         return;
      }

     (void)memset((char_t *) &req, 0, sizeof(req));

    // Adding required IP Address to req structure
    ptrSin = (struct sockaddr_in *)&req.arp_pa;
    ptrSin->sin_family = AF_INET;
    ptrSin->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipAddress.c_str());

    // Adding required MAC address to req structure
    (void)memcpy(req.arp_ha.sa_data, macAddress, 6);
    req.arp_flags = ATF_PERM | ATF_COM;
    (void)memcpy(req.arp_dev, device, IFNAMSIZ);

    if (ioctl(sockfd, SIOCSARP, (caddr_t)&req) < 0) {
        cout << "ARP assoc set failed" << endl;
        cout << "\nException caught : ioctl Failure in assocArp function in 
        IPService\n";
        (void)close(sockfd);
        return;
    }
    close(sockfd);
 }
```

'''
In case of IPV6 the structure "struct arpreq req" can't be used & i am unable to find any alternative structure for ipv6.
Can anyone suggest something about how to implement the functionality to enter Neighbour Entry in IPV6?

Comment: If you know some commands doing that, try [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html)-ing it to understand the relevant [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)

Comment: IPv6 NDP uses multiple tables (Neighbor Cache, Destination Cache, Prefix List, Default Router List). NDP subsumes the IPv4 ARP function, but has much more. You need to be intimately familiar with _[RFC 4861, Neighbor Discovery for IP version 6 (IPv6)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4861.html)_ before messing with the IPv6 tables.

Answer (score 0):

[ARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) protocol is limited to IPv4. In IPv6, MAC address resolution is handled by the [Neighbor Discovery Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbor_Discovery_Protocol) (a.k.a. ndisc).

In Linux, the easiest is to use the [rtnetlink API](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/rtnetlink.7.html) for interfacing with ndisc; `RTM_NEWNEIGH`, `RTM_DELNEIGH`, `RTM_GETNEIGH` commands can be used to add, delete or query the neighbor table.

See the source of [iproute2/ip/iproute.c](https://github.com/shemminger/iproute2/blob/50b668bdbf0ebc270495eb4b352d0c3982159d0a/ip/ipneigh.c) for an example usage.